# Send 'monitor reset halt' in GDB using MI commands

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb, bare-metal

I am using GDB to debug a Cortex-M0 processor. Using the normal default text interface, I can do it just fine. `monitor reset halt` is needed to restart the processor. Otherwise, I need to reset my debugging interface that the processor is attached to (OpenOCD through an ST/Link-V2).

I am trying to use the MI interpreter to automate this a bit, but have been oddly unable to figure out how this is done using the MI commands. Seems simple enough, but after reading through every page of the manual, I must have missed it.

I am using GCC-ARM 4.9.2015q3 from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always send a CLI command to the MI interpreter.  It can be done directly (just send `monitor reset halt`) or using `-interpreter-exec`.  The latter form is preferred, at least according to the gdb manual.

Comment: That was it. The actual command that worked was `interpreter console "monitor reset halt"`